# How do I total all values for checkout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to do some simple math with Ruby.

I have a model called `job_delivery_costs`. A user can add multiple job delivery costs to the checkout.

I can total each individual job delivery cost with `delivery_cost.quantity * delivery_cost.cost_per_unit` in the views, however I want to add the total of all the delivery costs to display at the end.

I developed this method:

```
def calculate_delivery_total(array)
    array.map(&:cost_per_unit).inject(0, &:+) * array.map(&:quantity).inject(0, &:+)
  end
```

But this is way off the mark. This is what I want to achieve:

```
cost_per_unit    quantity
22                3.00         =    66
18                2           =     36

total = 102
```

Comment: your question is not at all clear

Comment: Unless all your units are the same cost, your math is just wrong.

Comment: @Rahul there, i have done the math of what i want to achieve

Comment: @CodeGnome in the UK we say Maths, with an s. see my update

Comment: With or without an S, `84 * 5 == 102 #=> false`. Hence, your math is wrong because your orders of precedence are wrong. The answers below should yield the right answer, but unless you understand *why* your calculation was wrong, your accountants and stockholders will hate you.

Comment: @CodeGnome, i see what you're saying. Sure they will, it's mutual. I think it was more my lack of understanding of the 'inject method' and overall, how the numbers were being totted up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to sum cost per unit * quantity, then do it all in one operation:

```
 array.reduce(0) { |total, item| total + item.cost_per_unit * item.quantity }
```

Comment: could you explain what the difference is between reduce and inject?

Comment: There's no difference.  I just prefer reduce because it's found in other languages that I use.

Comment: This answer would be great if it were self-contained. If anyone wants to try Sean's answer in a REPL like irb or pry with the OPs data: `class Item < Struct.new(:cost_per_unit, :quantity); end; array = Item.new(22, 3), Item.new(18, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
array.sum { |item| item.cost_per_unit * item.quantity }
```

Comment: This looks right, but it requires ActiveSupport rather than standard Ruby. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum.

Comment: The question was tagged with `ruby-on-rails`

Comment: I agree. I didn't say it was wrong; in fact, I think your answer looks cleaner than the accepted answer. I'm just pointing out to future visitors that the answer can't be validated without ActiveSupport--failing to point that out might lead to undeserved downvotes when pasting your answer into a REPL yields an error. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

if you model is called `JobDeliveryCost` then the below would do your calculation in just one query, saving the `n + 1` resulting from looping over each row and overhead of `ActiveRecord` creating new objects

```
JobDeliveryCost.sum("cost_per_unit * quantity")
```